# How to give a type to a property of this

Tags: angular, typescript

```
ngOnInit() {

  let isTest: boolean = this.isTest || false;

  this.isTest: boolean = this.isTest || false;
}
```

Using `let` the compiled code becomes `var isTest = this.isTest || false` as you would expect but when assigning to `this` it becomes:

```
this.isTest;
boolean = this.isTest || true;
```

And also throws the error `boolean is not defined`, which makes sense.

What I don't understand however is why I can't define a type for a property of this `this` the way I'm doing it.

Why is this and what would be the correct way of doing it?

**EDIT:**

Apparently you can't *declare class members inside methods*, but would the same solution as @NitzanTomer gave apply for Angular 2's component input properties?

Example:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'test',
  inputs: [
    'isTest'
  ]
})

export class isTest implements OnInit {
  isTest: boolean;

  ngOnInit() {
    this.isTest = this.isTest || false;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't declare class members inside methods, it should be:

```
class YourClass {
    isTest: boolean;

    ngOnInit() {
        this.isTest = this.isTest || false;
    }

    ...
}
```

---

#### Edit

You can also declare class members in the constructor like this:

```
class YourClass {
    constructor(private isTest: boolean) { }
}
```

---

#### 2nd Edit

I'm not an angular developer, but based on examples it seems that you need to do the same as I answered, just that you sometimes decorate those members with `@Input`.

[For example](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-communication.html):

```
@Component({
    selector: 'hero-child',
    template: `
        <h3>{{hero.name}} says:</h3>
        <p>I, {{hero.name}}, am at your service, {{masterName}}.</p>
    `
})
export class HeroChildComponent {
    @Input() hero: Hero;
    @Input('master') masterName: string;
}
```

Or:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'hero-parent',
    template: `
        <h2>{{master}} controls {{heroes.length}} heroes</h2>
        <hero-child *ngFor="let hero of heroes"
            [hero]="hero"
            [master]="master">
        </hero-child>
    `
})
export class HeroParentComponent {
    heroes = HEROES;
    master: string = 'Master';
}
```

Comment: Same applies if `isTest` is an input of a component?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, can you edit your question with an example? Also, checked my revised answer, I added another way in which you can declare class members in typescript.

Comment: I updated question with an example. Ye I'm aware how to do it in the constructor but I don't want to put everything there as that would be the wrong way of doing it in my case as far as I'm aware.

Comment: I added examples of how to do that in angular. I've never used angular, but google helped.